# Facebook Javascript Canvas Login Redirect

Tags: javascript, facebook, redirect, canvas, authentication

I am building a facebook canvas application and want users, when they visit "apps.facebook.com/myApp", to be presented with the appropriate login dialogue immediately instead of showing my canvas page without having been logged in.  With all the different login flows, I am confused!

Using javascript, how do I do this?  Do I set the default canvas page to be a page with a script with a redirect url in it?

Answer (score 0):

You should not immediately present them with the login dialog, it is best practice to show some intro screen with information about your app first. Else there is only a small authorization information and no use will really know what the app is about. Then let the user click on a "Login/Use/Start/..." button to present the authorization popup with the FB.login function of the JavaScript SDK:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.login/

If you really want to require user authorization right at the beginning, user the PHP SDK:

https://github.com/facebook/facebook-php-sdk

See "`$facebook->getLoginUrl()`" - just redirect to the resulting URL if the user is not logged in.

Comment: How come I am presented with the login for theFlowGame when I type, directly into my address bar, "apps.facebook.com/theflowgame" then?

Comment: hard to say without your code, but i assume you are using the php sdk for the login - or you immediately invoke FB.login, which is also not a good idea.

Comment: after all didn´t you program your app? so you should know what happens in it ;) - you wrote "i want them to be presented", not that it´s like that right now.

Comment: I get your point... but I guess my question is simply... what are the creators of "theflowgame" doing so that you see what you do when you have not logged into the game and you type the url, "apps.facebook.com/theflowgame"

Comment: well, i will edit my answer then, even though it´s a very bad form to require user authorization immediately... ;)